# How do I kill myself?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My King of Ireland just died, but the problem is the child I had groomed for succession, my first son was murdered sometime ago, and now my second son inherited my kingdom. He is "Slow" and basically has 0 on 3 of the stats making him really useless.

My Succession Laws are Primogeniture, so the next heir is his brother or the 3rd Son of the original king. I want to kill off the "Slow" son ASAP.

The Slow son is pretty much hated by everyone, but I have been playing as him for a while and he has not been murdered by anyone yet.

So the question is how the hell do I get myself killed? So as to pass on the kingdom to my brother.

Comment: A quick "cheat" is to load your save, but select to play as your brother. You can then work to usurp your former self. This is particularly good if your brother has a strong claim to the throne.

Comment: +1, [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) [site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions) [has](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/my-wife-is-stuck-in-a-wall-can-i-save-her) [the](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34804/how-can-i-find-lesbians) [best](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/are-there-any-benefits-to-getting-drunk) [titles](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/the-internet-keeps-me-from-dreaming) :-P