# I cannot kill my reflection, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

In the water temple, you are forced to fight a reflection of yourself. However, I can't seem to land a hit. ***Does anybody have advice on a good method of self-murder?***

Comment: This question should be added to the archive of "bizarre without context" ones :D

Comment: Title [How do I kill myself](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127170/how-do-i-kill-myself) was already taken :(

Comment: You just asked 2 back to back questions about killing yourself in two different games. Is there something wrong with living sir?

Comment: I think this question has a misleading title.  While Dark Link may look and act similarly to your character on OoT, he is *NOT* you.  When you talk about killing yourself, that means ways of inflicting self-damage, like environmental hazards / fall damage.  What you are really asking about is ways to kill dark link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have discovered in my 7+ times fighting Dark Link AKA Shadow Link there are two main ways to go about defeating him:

1) You can use the Megaton Hammer as you sole weapon. The reason this works is because Dark Link copied all of the items and weaponry that you had when you fought Phantom Ganon (which if you had been going along with the game chronologically, you should have fought by now) he copied your items and weaponry, and you had received the Megaton Hammer since that encounter. The reason not to use your Biggoron's Sword will be covered in reason #2.

2) You can use sword and shield. This only recommended if you want to spend the longest time fighting him, because if you use this method he will immediately start using what ever weapon you choose to fight him with. If you use the Biggoron's Sword he will count it as a sword not the Biggoron's Sword.

**One final warning:** If you are playing Ocarina of Time 3D, Dark Link will progressively gain weapon usage the longer it takes you to defeat him.

Comment: I didn't know about Phantom Gannondorf, if i get every item from every temple but not defeat the bosses then defeat Phantom Gannondorf then go and fight Dark Link will he be at his strongest

Comment: Technically I doesn't matter if you fight Phantom Gannondorf or not, that fight was just the explanation of where Dark Link got his powers.

Answer (score 3):

The Reflection (Dark Link) will get stronger the longer the battle is drawn out; to the point where at times he'll jump on your sword and cut you. So you want to end the battle quickly. Some things I do:

1. Use the hammer. No idea why, but when I first fought him it always worked.
2. Use Din's Fire to get some space. It seems that he'll either get hurt and drop back into the water or defend and get pushed back which gives you a reprieve.
3. Don't thrust. If you're Z Targeting and moving forward when you attack you'll thrust; this is when he jumps on your sword. At the start of the battle it's not a big problem since he just stands there before back-flipping, however afterwords he'll slash you before back-flipping.
4. Carry nothing but fairies. Unless I need a bottle for something else I always have a full stock of them.

As I said, the first time I used the hammer and it seemed to always be effective. However after I got more confident in my skills I ditched that method and had a straight up brawl with Dark Link with just swords and shields.

Comment: Alright, good answer. I have heard that there are certain ways to attack him without being hit in kind, maybe finding a walk through like Zelda dungeon? (Yes, I use walk throughs. Problem? :P )

Comment: Commentary from an uninformed: I know in The Wind Waker you can press the control stick towards Link's left or right while targetting to control the direction of your horizontal slice. Maybe you need to do this to hit the side that Dark Link's shield isn't on.

Comment: I don't remember where I heard this (may have been from Navi) but shadow link can read your moves while z-targeting and will block all of your sword swings while doing so. That's why most people use the hammer.

Comment: You can also use the biggorn sword. It does more damage than the hammer and Dark Link cannot block it.

Comment: @Toomai you can't do that in OoT, 3DS version or N64

Answer (score 0):

If you talk to Medigoron in Goron City as an adult, he'll sell you the Giant's Knife. If you use it too much, it'll break. Why am I telling you this? Well, one of Dark Link's favorite tricks is to stand on your sword when you jab him. But the broken Giant's Knife is too short to stand on! So you get a free hit and he can't touch you. Just note that if you have the Biggoron's Sword you won't be able to get the Giant's Knife anymore.